# Getting %def references in mako python

Tags: python, mako

is there a way to use %def references somehow, basic idea being:

```
% if condition_a:
%    func = %def_a
% elif condition_b:
%    func = %def_b
... etc ...

${func( params )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes like this:

```
% if condition_a:
<% func = def_a %>
% elif condition_b:
<% func = def_b %>
% endif

${func( params )}
```

@timmy: I have no idea what you mean, maybe this?

```
<% func = some_dict[key] %>
${func( params )}
```

You can put any Python code inside `<% .. %>`, see the mako docs!